# Represent relations between entities using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I want to represent a series of data using the `networkx` library for Python3 but I do not know how to approach the problem.

Basically I have a `relation` between two `entities` which is in a csv file called `nations.csv`. It looks like this:

```
China, Economicaid, Egypt
China, Economicaid, Indonesia
USSR, Economicaid, Cuba 
USSR, Economicaid, India
USSR, Economicaid, Poland
UK, Economicaid, India 
UK, Economicaid, Jordan
USA, Economicaid, Brazil
```

Understanding that the first row is one of the entity which is related to the third row (entity 2) between the second one:

[image: relation]

I've parsed the csv file in order to store each of the rows in a dictionary, as follows:

```
d = {}
d['entity1'] = []
d['relation'] = []
d['entity2'] = []

dictReader = csv.DictReader(open('nations.csv', 'rt'), fieldnames = 
['entity1', 'relation', 'entity2'], delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')

for row in dictReader:
    for key in row:
        d[key].append(row[key])
```

What I've managed to do is plot the nodes using the function `add_node()` like the following example:

```
import csv
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


d = {}
d['entity1'] = []
d['relation'] = []
d['entity2'] = []

dictReader = csv.DictReader(open('nations.csv', 'rt'), fieldnames = ['entity1', 'relation', 'entity2'], delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')

for row in dictReader:
    for key in row:
        d[key].append(row[key])

print()

for i in range (1, len(d['entity1'])):
    r.append(d['entity1'][i])

for k in range (1, len(d['entity2'])):
    o.append(d['entity2'][k])


G=nx.Graph()

for j in range(len(r)):
    G.add_node(r[j])
    G.add_node(o[j])

nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels = True, node_size = 500)

plt.show()
```

But the problem comes when I want to represent the edges between the nodes, because it is not only the edge itself, it also has its own label with the meaning.

Comment: what are the edge "meanings"? you can add attributes to edges either [on construction](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.add_edge.html) or [to existing edges](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_edge_attributes.html).  Would a text label be enough?

Comment: @Bonlenfum the edge represent each relation so it has to have its own label depending on the type of relation. In my `nations.csv` example I put only one type of relation, but there are plenty of them.

Comment: If more than one type of relation is possible between the same pair of nodes, you should look at multigraphs.  But given the accepted answer below, I guess that you mean the relation differs between different node pairs, in which case the edge attributes solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the flag `with_labels` should really be called `with_node_labels` as it triggers only the plotting of the node labels. Hence you need to manually add the edge labels (`networkx.draw_networkx_edge_labels`) after having drawn the graph (networkx.draw`), and you need to 1) plot on the same axis, and 2) use the same graph layout for both plots.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import csv

# load data
dictReader = csv.DictReader(open('nations.csv', 'rt'), fieldnames = ['entity1', 'relation', 'entity2'], delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')

# create a more amenable data structure
edge_to_label = {(d['entity1'], d['entity2']) : d['relation'] for d in dictReader}

# create graph
G = nx.from_edgelist(edge_to_label.keys())

# precompute layout (default layout used here)
layout = nx.layout.fruchterman_reingold_layout(G)

# create figure so we plot the graph and labels on the same plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

# draw graph
nx.draw(G, pos=layout, ax=ax, with_labels=True)

# draw labels using the same, pre-computed graph layout
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=layout, edge_labels=edge_to_label, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: And is there any way to adjust the viewing conditions in the code to make it look the best way possible? Because with few lines the graph is small, but I need to put many more entities.

Comment: You should really open another question if it is not a directly related follow-up. Your follow-up is about layout options for networks with many nodes, which is definitely unrelated. That being said, I would suggest that you start reading the networkx code documentation and playing around with the options. You should in particular familiarize yourself with the different layout options for the node placement; maybe there is one that meets your needs. Without access to your data, nobody will be able to give you a decent answer (other than by chance).

Comment: Even with access to your data, what appears to be the "best way possible" will be a matter of taste rather than any objective, measurable criterion.

Comment: sorry.   this answer doesnt add the information of the label into the graph G but only drawing it out right?  But relation can have attributes in networkx,  why dont we add this information into the graph G first?